# Hibernate inserts duplicate rows on ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

To preface, I'm new to hibernate (and java in general) so bear with me.  So I'm trying to set up two entities, Driver and Address, where multiple drivers can have the same address (so, ManyToOne).  Everything I read online is about One to Many relationships but I can't find any for the other way around.  I want to be able to make post requests to my endpoint with different drivers that have the same address without creating duplicate address entries.  Here are the (somewhat abbreviated) Driver and Address entities and DriverService respectfully.

When I remove the uniqueConstraints from the address table, I can make multiple post requests to the endpoint and have the same address duplicated in the database. I want to be able to make multiple post requests and have all of the drivers with the same addresses link to the single address in the DB, rather than just continue making duplicate entries. What am I missing?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "driver")
public class Driver implements Serializable {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Address getAddress() {
    return address_id;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "address",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"street", "city", "state", "zip"}))
public class Address implements Serializable {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;


@Service
```

public class DriverService {

```
private final DriverRepository driverRepository;

public DriverService (DriverRepository driverRepository) {
    this.driverRepository = driverRepository;
}

public Driver createDriver(DriverDTO dto) {
    Address address = new Address();
    DriversLicense driversLicense = new DriversLicense();
    Driver driver = new Driver();

    address.setStreet(dto.getStreet());
    address.setCity(dto.getCity());
    address.setState(dto.getState());
    address.setZip(dto.getPostal());

    Date issueDate = new Date();
    Date expDate = new Date();
    Date dob = new Date();

    try {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        issueDate = sdf.parse(dto.getIssued());
        expDate = sdf.parse(dto.getExpires());
        dob = sdf.parse(dto.getDob());
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    driversLicense.setDriversLicenseNumber(dto.getId());
    driversLicense.setIssuedDate(issueDate);
    driversLicense.setExpirationDate(expDate);

    driver.setFirstName(dto.getFirst());
    driver.setLastName(dto.getLast());
    driver.setMiddleName(dto.getMiddle());
    driver.setBirthDate(dob);
    driver.setEyeColor(dto.getEyes());
    driver.setGender(dto.getSex());
    driver.setHeight(dto.getHeight());
    driver.setAddress(address);
    driver.setDriversLicense(driversLicense);

    driverRepository.save(driver);

    return driver;
}
```

}

Comment: It's hard to tell since you haven't posted the actual code that saves the entities. My guess is that you're simply calling `entityManager.persist(driver)` and expecting JPA to do the rest. You need to query for an existing `Address` and, if found, assign it to `driver.address_id` before saving the `driver`

Comment: Updated the OP with the service.  I've tried querying for an existing address but I now get the error "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist:" for the address entity.

Comment: 'detached entity passed to persist' means you're almost there. Wrap your service method in a transaction

Comment: @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "recursosidRecursos")......solve all my problem.